# Using Ruby on Rails over existing DB - simple console tests are generating errors?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

ANSWER EDIT:

The problem seemed to be that I have a column with the name of "class" -- I found a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/safe_attributes) that appears to allow it to work despite the use a reserved word as a column name. Thanks all for the help.

Question:

I have an existing MySQL DB I am trying to build an app over and the original table name does not follow conventions, so I set it in the model.

Model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "event_20140204"
end
```

I have tried multiple tests with both the controller/views, but I think the simplest answer will probably come from the console. I am very new to Rails, so I hope I am showing the problem correctly:

Example column_names:

```
irb(main):004:0> Event.column_names
=> ["sid", "signature", "timestamp", "unified_event_id", "unified_event_ref", "unified_ref_time", "priority", continued ... ]
```

Example record (first):

```
irb(main):001:0> Event.first
Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `event_20140204`.* FROM `event_20140204`  LIMIT 1
=> #<Event sid: 3, signature: "Example signature", timestamp: "2014-02-04 00:02:08", unified_event_id: 3, unified_event_ref: 3, unified_ref_time: "2014-02-04 00:02:08", priority: 1, [ continued ... ] >
```

And then trying to show a simple field, it crashes with this error:

```
irb(main):002:0> e = Event.first
< same as above, code omitted >
irb(main):003:0> e.timestamp
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_generated_attribute_method' for "misc-attack":String
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:199:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /var/www/html/ir/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

`misc-attack` is another field. It happens when I try to show any of the columns using e.colum_name.

Another simple test:

```
irb(main):041:0> e = Event.all.limit(5)
Event Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  `event_20140204`.* FROM `event_20140204`  LIMIT 5
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>
irb(main):042:0> e.count
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM `event_20140204`  LIMIT 5) subquery_for_count
=> 5
irb(main):043:0> e.each do |event|
irb(main):044:1*     event.timestamp
irb(main):045:1> end
Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `event_20140204`.* FROM `event_20140204`  LIMIT 5
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:111:in `read_attribute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:47:in `__temp__36c6163737'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:215:in `init_with'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:52:in `instantiate'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:48:in `block in find_by_sql'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `block in each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:48:in `map'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:48:in `find_by_sql'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:603:in `exec_queries'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:487:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:231:in `to_a'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
    from (irb):43
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /var/www/html/ir/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'irb(main):046:0>
```

The `NoMethodError: undefined method []' for nil:NilClass` was the cause of my misery in my controller/views tests. I would do a simple do/each loop to show the data for each column and it would always show the Rails error screen with the `undefined method` problem.

Does anyone have any idea?

Edit:

The (unmodified) schema from MySQL, as requested. It is a sguil event database:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid               | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cid               | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| signature         | varchar(255)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| signature_gen     | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| signature_id      | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| signature_rev     | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp         | datetime             | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| unified_event_id  | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| unified_event_ref | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| unified_ref_time  | datetime             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| priority          | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| class             | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status            | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | 0       |       |
| src_ip            | int(10) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| dst_ip            | int(10) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| src_port          | int(10) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| dst_port          | int(10) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| icmp_type         | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| icmp_code         | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ip_proto          | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_ver            | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_hlen           | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_tos            | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_len            | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_id             | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_flags          | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_off            | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_ttl            | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_csum           | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_modified     | datetime             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| last_uid          | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| abuse_queue       | enum('Y','N')        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| abuse_sent        | enum('Y','N')        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: have you tried `set_table_name "event_20140204"`?

Comment: I set the table name in my model. Where would I try and use set_table_name? On the Event object in the console? It seems to see the table fine.

Comment: Is that the entire model? Can you add the schema of that table to the question?

Comment: (Or perhaps try restarting `spring` - I've seen it do some strange things)

Comment: `class Event < ActiveRecord::Base  self.set_table_name "event_20140204" end`
this line : `SELECT  'event_20140204'.* FROM 'event_20140204'` has me thinking it's not recognizing the table quite right. It's attempting to pull an object titled 'event_20140204' from table 'event20140204' which is obviously not right. Unless I'm reading something wrong.

Comment: @sevenseacat That is the entire model. I was just trying to start off and make sure simple stuff worked before going well into any functionality. I restarted spring and it does not seem to have made a difference. That was a great idea though.

Micah, the table name is event_20140204 and when I run the exact query the console prints back, it runs fine in MySQL. I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails generates accessor methods for each of the columns. A corollary of this is that an attribute named "class" is a very bad thing: the accessor method with overwrite the builtin method of that name so

```
event.class
```

Returns the value of that attribute instead of its class, which will call all sorts of inscrutable errors

I'm not aware of a good way of dealing with this - ideally you'd want to be able to alias the attribute to a safe name without changing the source table.

Comment: Great spot. I found a gem that seems to allow it to work fine: https://rubygems.org/gems/safe_attributes